# Encerrar cada valor en unos corchetes ([]) usando group_concat

Tags: mysql

Amigos, tengo una duda, espero me puedan ayudar.
Resulta que estoy utilizando group_concat para unir varios valores en base a un solo ID.
Ejemplo:

```
select idper,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_name)
from persona
group by idper
```

El resultado
|idper | id_name |
|:---- |:--------|
|1255  |146,2,1,5|
|4458  |146,2,5  |

Sin embargo, necesito que estos numeros de "id_name" queden encerrados en corchetes, así:
|idper | id_name |
|:---- |:--------|
|1255  |[146],[2],[1],[5]|
|4458  |[146],[2],[5]  |

¿Alguna idea de como darle ese formato?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como esto, con una subconsulta en el FROM:

```
select
    id_per,
    group_concat(id_name)
from
(
select 
    idper,
    CONCAT('[',id_name,']') as id_name
from 
    persona
)tbl
groub by id_per
```

Comment: Gracias @Vicent me funcionó perfecto, solo que en lugar del from lo ocupé directamente en un left join

Comment: @MatíasUrrea puedes dar la respuesta como correcta.